# How to write the python raw sampling function to generate a random number using normal distribution?

Tags: python, statistics, sampling

Where is this source code of python statistics and numpy?

I would like understand how it generate random number from normal distribution

I find school math using probability as a result from table to do sampling topic.

If no category more than 20% probability, it seems can not determine which threshold of probability that can be selected.

Why not use [a, a, b, b, c, c, d, d, e, e] and then random select from a list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Where is this source code of python statistics and numpy?*

General way to get where file with source code is located is to `print` module. For example for [numpy.random.rand](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.rand.html) do

```
import numpy
print(numpy.random)
```

which will give you full path to  `.py` file for `numpy.random`.

Comment: print(numpy.random.normal) , built-in method normal of mtrand.RandomState object at 0x11ed7efa8>   Shown in my iPad, should I run in x86 computer?

Comment: Do `print(numpy.random)` not `print(numpy.random.normal)` (1st is module, whilst 2nd is not)